# How to solve circular dependency in python

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I learnt that `isinstance(object, type)` and `issubclass(type, object)`. I want to write self-defined class act like `object` and `type`, but how to solve circular dependency?

```
declare class MyType

class MyObject(metaclass=MyType):
    pass

class MyType(MyObject, type):
    pass
```

Comment: What's this for? Mostly I'm curious, but I'm also wondering if this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). From what I understand, Python has `type` and `object` set up like that only because the class hierarchy has to start somewhere, so IDK why other classes would need to replicate it.